# onclick для div в методе класса js

Tags: javascript, slider

Здравствуйте, прошу помощи, объяснений, примеров..) Пишу слайдер своими силами для сайта (намеренно не использую библиотеки) на чистом [js](/questions/tagged/js) по возможности универсальный.

Решил сделать прототип класса для слайдера, их несколько на странице, вроде бы все нормально работает, но **не могу повесить** (или понять почему не работает) **событие** `onclick` на `div` при котором будет отрабатываться метод экземпляра класса - `scrollLeft(arrg)`. Этот же метод используется и в другом методе - `enableAutoScroll()`, который работает! Должно быть дело в оформлении кода.

В общем разметка такая:

```
<div class="slider relation" id="slider-1">        // Слайдер
    <div class="relation_ratio ratio-4x1"></div>      // Адаптива
    <div class="relation_content">                    // Контент
        <div class="slider_btn slider_left"></div>        // Кнопка - влево
        <div class="slides_line">                         // Пикчи
            // <a>image</a>  
            //     ...
        </div>
        <div class="slider_btn slider_right"></div>       // Кнопка - вправо
    </div>
</div>
```

Класс и проблемный метод **setButtonsEvent**:

```
Slider = function(id_name) {
    this.id_name = id_name;
    this.auto_scroll = 0;
    this.offset = 0;
    this.timeoutId = undefined;
    this.number_of_childes = this.getSlidesLine().children.length;
    this.getSlidesLine().style.left = this.offset + "%";
    this.setButtonsEvent();
}

Slider.prototype.setButtonsEvent = function() {
    this.getLeftButton().addEventListener('click', this.scrollLeft(3));
    //    Property 'handleEvent' is not callable.
    this.getRightButton().onclick = this.scrollRight();
    //    Не работает
    //    Пробовал просто "this.scrollRight;" - тогда при загрузке страницы просто выполняется эта функция (прокручивает слайдер один раз) и по нажатию также ничего не происходит. Но при этом сообщает, что "this.getSlidesLine is not a function"
    return this;
}
```

В классе присутствуют методы для получения объектов, типа:

```
Slider.prototype.getSlidesLine = function() {
    return document.querySelector("#" + this.id_name + " > .relation_content > .slides_line");
};

Slider.prototype.getLeftButton = function() {
    return document.querySelector("#" + this.id_name + " > .relation_content > .slider_btn.slider_left");
};

Slider.prototype.getRightButton = function() {
    return document.querySelector("#" + this.id_name + " > .relation_content > .slider_btn.slider_right");
};
```

ну и сам **scrollLeft**:

```
Slider.prototype.scrollLeft = function(divider = 3) {
    if(Math.abs(this.offset) / 100 >= this.number_of_childes / divider - 1) this.offset = 0;
    else this.offset -= 100;
    this.getSlidesLine().style.left = this.offset + "%";
    return this;
};
```

Так же буду рад замечаниям по поводу оформления строк кода.